# How i can get the fullclassname if i only know a part of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the classname from an element, but I only know a part of the name.

```
<div class="anotherclass my-class-no-1 onemoreclass...">div>
```

I can call the element with this

```
$([class*="my-class-no-"]...
```

But how can I get the complete classname?

Thanks a lot for explaining.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding matched classname in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552297/finding-matched-classname-in-jquery)

Comment: `$("[class*=my-class-no-]")[0].className` - will give you all the classes as a single string or `$("[class*=my-class-no-]")[0].classList` as a DOMTokenList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use className and search the class name containing your substring

```js
let subclass = 'my-class-no-';

$('[class*="'+subclass+'"]').each(function() {
  let name = this.className.split(' ').find((className) => {
    return className.indexOf(subclass) !== -1;
  });

  console.log(name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anotherclass my-class-no-1 onemoreclass">
  <div>
```

Comment: Hi, i think thats the way it goes, but i have a problem - in my code i have no "this" so get the error message classname is undefined!?

Comment: @mikeD you use className on an jQuery object ? If yes use `.attr('class')` instead `.className`

Answer (score 0):

try it

```js
 console.log( $(".anotherclass").attr("class").split(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="anotherclass my-class-no-1 onemoreclass"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like that:
(See comments in the snipper)

```js
var search = "my-class-no-"; // Added to enter the searched class only once
var elms = $("[class*=" + search + "]"); // Get match
var classstr = elms.attr("class"); // Get the class attribute

// Split the string class attribute string to only keep the class that was searched
var myClass = classstr.substring(classstr.indexOf(search)).split(" ")[0];
console.log(myClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anotherclass my-class-no-1 onemoreclass"></div>
```